# Significance of correlation with only 11 datapoints

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, bootstrap, small-sample

I am currently working on my thesis and calculating some simple correlation coefficients. I only have 11 datapoints available, but I would like to assess the statistial significance of my results. The asymptotic p-values are not significant at the 10% level.

Because of the small sample, I additionally computed bootstrapped confidence intervals, which are, to my surprise, different from zero at the 10% level. My question: Can I claim statistical significance of my results according to my bootstrapped confidence intervals? Or is this not valid because of the small sample?

Cheers and many thanks in advance!
Chris

Answer (score 3):

As long as you did the bootstrapping correctly, yes, I think you can.

Of course, there might be other reasons why correlation is not a good measure, but the bootstrapping should get around the small sample size. (see e.g. the Anscombe quartet)

With only 11 points, you might be able to do a permutation test instead of bootstrapping.

Comment: With "correct" I suppose you mean pairwise bootstrap, which jointly draws from the two variables.

Comment: I just wanted to be careful not to give more approval than I can; bootstrapping is complex. There's no code or details in the post, so ... I prefaced my remarks with that qualifier.